# Calculate fields own class and different class? - Openerp

Tags: python, function, arguments, odoo, self

I have problems with this code. I Hope could have some help.

```python
class demo(osv.osv):

    _inherit = 'compresores.datos'

    def _buscar_compresor(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        auxpower = self.browse(cr, uid, id).power
        obj = self.pool.get('compresores.datos')
        ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [])
        res = obj.read(cr, uid, ids, ['name', 'id', 'comp_a1','comp_a2'], context)
        res = [(r['id'], r['name'], r['comp_a1'],r['comp_a2']) 
        for r in res 
            if (r['comp_a1'] >= auxpower)]
        return res

    _name = "demo_datos"
    _description = "Demo"
    _columns = {
        'power': fields.float('Potencia frigorifica',digits=(3,2)),
        'compresor1': fields.selection(_buscar_compresor,method="True", type="char", size=256, string="Compresor" ),

    }

demo()
```

Here is the XML

```python
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="demo_form">
            <field name="name">demo.form</field>
            <field name="model">demo_datos</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="DEMO" version="7.0">
                    <group col='4' colspan='2'>
                        <field name="power" class="oe_inline" />
                        <field name="compresor1" />
                     </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="demo_tree">
            <field name="name">demo.tree</field>
            <field name="model">demo_datos</field>
            <field name="type">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="DEMO general">
                    <field name="power" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

I have the field `power` in my class. And I need a function that compare if the field in another class (comp_a1) is higher and return the registers from that class.

I use `self.pool.get` to call the other class and it's okay and works. But when I use `self.browse` to read the field `power` (with auxpower) in the same function there are problems with arguments I think... what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

**fields.selection**

A field which allows the user to make a selection between various predefined values.

Syntax:

```
fields.selection([('value','display'), ('value','display')],
                   'Title' [, Optional Parameters]),
```

Format of the selection parameter: list of tuples of strings of the form:

```
[('value', 'display'),('value', 'display'),('value', 'display')]
```

**NOTE**

```
_inherit = 'compresores.datos'
_name = "demo_datos"
```

if you want to extend/update features of an existing models then you can use **_inherit**, but **_name** with **_inherit** will be created new model **_name** which contains all the features of **_inherit** model.

You should update your code in following manner,

```
class demo(osv.osv):

    _inherit = 'compresores.datos'

    def _buscar_compresor(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        obj_comp = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
        if obj_comp:
            auxpower = obj.power
        obj = self.pool.get('compresores.datos')
        ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [])
        res = obj.read(cr, uid, ids, ['name', 'id', 'comp_a1','comp_a2'], context)
        dict = [(r['id'], r['name']) for r in res if (r['comp_a1'] >= auxpower)]
        return dict

    _columns = {
        'power': fields.float('Potencia frigorifica',digits=(3,2)),
        'compresor1': fields.selection(_buscar_compresor,method="True", type="char", size=256, string="Compresor" ),

    }

demo()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
When i try to update the module there is an XML error now… but my XML is okay…
I will edit the question to show the XML.
Regards

Comment: Anyways I need help with the auxpower, whenever I change the code there is an error with xml or arguments... in this case xml

File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 1557, in _validate
    raise except_orm('ValidateError', '\n'.join(error_msgs))
except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error al validar el campo (s) dearch:Invalid XML for View Architecture!')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I use this code now and, for the moment, it's work.

```
def _buscar_compresor(self, cr, uid, ids, power, arg, context=None):
    aux1={}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        aux1= record.power
    records = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
    obj = self.pool.get('compresores.datos')
    ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [])
    res3 = obj.read(cr, uid, ids, ['nombre', 'id', 'comp_a1'], context)
    res3 = [(str(r['nombre']), str(r['tipo_gas']), int(r['comp_a1']) 
    for r in res3 
        if (r['comp_a1'] >= aux1 )]
    resultado = {}
    for r in records:
        resultado[r.id] = str(res3) 
    return resultado
```